# Add table to WordPress database

Tags: customization, database, scripts

I want to add an extra table on my WordPress database and I intend to 
query it with a custom script that will be embedded to WordPress.

I'm worrying if this is a safe way to do it, or I should go with the
option of adding an entirely new database, not a table on WordPress, as future
updates of WordPress system might wipe my custom table? Any experience
with such a scenario. Is this a valid risk/worry, or I should just create
the table on the WordPress database, instead of creating another db, and connect
to that new db in my custom script.

Thank you.

Comment: To answer your question, yes you can add a table without worry. To me the basic question is: Do I really need the extra table? Can I do it (what I am trying to do) using only WordPress API?

Comment: Since this has been viewed 2K times I thought this answer might help some other people. Yes, it is safe and people do it all the time. Here is a good resource for how: https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no risk in creating new table in WP Database. Infact many well known and giant plugins, like Woocomerce do this.

You can also opt for creating new database but creating new table is not at all risky...

Hope I am clear enough...

Comment: Hello,
Yes I have noticed that, however I wanted to make sure as I'm new to the world of wp and I just don't want to regret making any decision that might result dumb in the future.
Thank you

Comment: Yes, creating new tables is quite common, when warranted. WP will not remove custom tables when it updates - it only affects tables it knows about. If you are just trying to add extra data to posts/pages/custom post types, you should probably use postmeta instead, as you don't need to mess with anything more custom like a separate table. But if you're adding data that's not related to anything else in the WP database, custom table is the right way to go. This should be the accepted answer. :)

Comment: You are right, I totally agree with what you said, as this is precisely what I was thinking